# Answer after modify questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/father-and-son-who-were-active-players-at-the-same-time) was modified to take possible to choose a correct answer.

The last version limits the field to NFL/NBA/NHL/MLB tournaments, but there were a lot of reply posted before the updating. So those reply seems wrong or offtopic with the risk of downvote, how is it possible to prevent this?

By now I add a comment with "This reply was posted when the answer was not limited to "NFL/NBA/NHL/MLB" tournaments (only to prevent downvoting)"

Answer (score 2):

My opinion on that question is that it shouldn't have been modified.  The rationale to modifying it was "to allow an answer to be chosen right", but there wouldn't have been any reason not to choose an answer with or without that.  The dilemma pointed to a weakness in the question - it was a list question - and drove [my meta question about it](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/community-wiki-for-list-type-questions?cb=1).

Either way, green checkmark doesn't mean "The one and only correct answer", it means "the most helpful answer".  The fact that a question doesn't have a single correct answer is unimportant, except in whether it's on topic at all or not - and clearly this site is okay with these kinds of questions, so it's fine.

So, I think the edit should probably be rolled back, as it turned it into a chameleon question (substantially changing the question after answers have been given).

Comment: The site is *not* clearly okay with my question, since it was closed.

Comment: It was closed, and then reopened.  That means it's okay.  :)  Limiting it to a few sports doesn't suddenly make it better, it's still a list.

Comment: Well it was only reopened after I limited it to a few sports. :)  Otherwise the question  qualified as "too broad".

Comment: I don't think that specifically had anything to do with it.  At least, nobody commented on my meta question to that effect.  If it becomes a problem we can flag a moderator and ask them to work it out, though.  Some people though do object to list questions inevitably - but to me that's fine if the site is generally okay with them.  In your case, changing the question invalidated many of the answers, which is unfortunate and why it generally shouldn't be changed once many answers have come.

Comment: I disagree with your recent edit.  See [my answer](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/553/1723) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close the question as it was originally written.  The wording in the question doesn't limit the answers at all.  It could be any sport in the world, at any level.  The fact that the answers just kept coming in from sports all over the world (including a list of [18 times that it has occurred in Cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/6912/1723)*) indicated to me quite clearly that the question was a list question that was way too broad.  I also left a comment indicating this.

After the question was edited by @pacoverflow, the original question author, to limit it in scope to the four U.S. major leagues, I voted to reopen and deleted my comment.

I still think that the question is too broad when it is not limited to a finite number of sports, and I would like to see the question reverted back to Revision 2.

---

<sub>*The 18 father/son Cricketer pairs were all fathers and sons who played *in the same match*, which means that the number of father/son pairs who simply played cricket at the same time is probably much higher.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand how the number of sports is relevant. It's a list question either way. Either that's okay - some sites allow them, usually with a CW answer - or it's not.

Comment: Particularly limiting it to 'American Sports' seems pernicious to me; this is an international site after all.

Comment: @Joe The reason that the sports in the question should be limited is that, without a limit, the answers can be almost infinite.  The way it is currently written, it is a brainstorming exercise.  If I played softball with my father once, does that count?  As the question is currently written, it should.

Comment: @Joe Yes, this is an international site.  I wouldn't be opposed to another question asking about father/son pairs in FIFA, or in professional cricket, for example.  But a single question like this about any sport at any level anywhere is too broad, in my opinion.

Comment: @BenMiller And about a year and a half later, it has been closed as too broad as a revelation of the reasons you state.