# I believe this question should be reopened

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/father-and-son-who-were-active-players-at-the-same-time-in-nfl-nba-nhl-mlb) of mine is currently closed as "too broad".

The original version (Revision 1) of the question was closed as too broad.  Then I made an edit (Revision 2) to narrow the scope of the question.  After that, it was reopened.  Then someone else reverted the question back to Revision 1, and later it was closed again for being too broad.  Then I reverted the question back to Revision 2, with the narrower scope, where the question now stands.

I think that since the question was reopened after Revision 2, it should be reopened again now that it's back to Revision 2.

Comment: It's still too broad, whether or not list questions are considered acceptable. And since the answer on that meta post has only two answers with a collective score of 5, using that as evidence of a consensus would make it an extremely tenuous conclusion.

Comment: @Nij I do not believe it is too broad now, given that only 2 of the answers relate to the NFL/MLB/NBA/NHL.  I only cited the meta post as the reason for why it was reverted to the broad version of the question (I will edit this question to remove that citation).  My main point is that it wasn't too broad at Revision 2, at which point it was reopened, and now it's back to Revision 2.

Comment: Reference: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/548/community-wiki-for-list-type-questions

Comment: "Too broad" isn't defined by how many answers there are already, it's defined by how many answers may be possible in the future - otherwise we would never be able to use that reason for unanswered questions. Only two *of the current answers* relate to the four leagues you list. That still doesn't mean it's a narrow scope! There may well be another twenty possible answers for those leagues; the fact that they haven't been made yet, doesn't mean they couldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let me defend @Joe's decision to roll back your edit which narrowed down the scope to only 4 leagues, NFL/NBA/NHL/MLB. If you read the answers, many of them have answers that have nothing to do with those 4 leagues. Your edit actually invalidated those answers. That kind of edit is not encouraged, especially when there are a lot of answers that are based on the pre-edited version of the question.
2. As @Nij mentioned, your question still reads too broad. And what is it that you can't find on the internet? Sports SE was not designed to be a Googling service. At least you should have narrowed your question along the lines of:

> I tried to find if there have been a father and his son who played at
>   the same time in XYZ leagues, and I found this and that. Are there any other
>   cases?

If you had narrowed down your question to some reasonable degree, I think your question is on-topic. As it stands, I don't think it is on-topic.

3. Your question received a total of 15 answers, what more do you expect?

A request to a moderator: I think the question should be rolled back to the first version as the current version invalidates many answers.

Comment: I'm going to let this sit until the community fleshes this out.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Take your time, please. Nothing seems to be urgent. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my two cents to this old question.

The question was simply too broad as originally written.  [I wrote about this before in another meta answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/553/1723), but basically, there are so many possible answers to this question that it will never be fully answered.  I voted to close the question a couple of days after it was asked.

Unfortunately, lots of answers got added before it was closed 5 days later.  You edited the question to narrow the scope and make it answerable, which I supported and voted to reopen.  Unfortunately, it was really too late at this point, as many people didn't like the fact that there were so many answers that got invalidated.  The question got reverted back, where it stayed, open, for a year and a half.  During that time, it continued to gain answer after answer of obscure examples.  It was the epitome of a bad list question.  Finally it was closed as too broad, again.

Unfortunately, at this point, the question has too much baggage to reopen.  [List questions are tricky](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/560/1723): when you ask them, you don't know how common an occurrence something is, so you don't know if it will be too broad or not.  And once the broad question has been asked and answered with lots of examples, it is really too late to try to narrow it.

If you really want to salvage the question, the best thing to do is probably to revert the wording back to the broad question, and leave it closed.  Then, if you want to ask about something like this in *one* sport, ask a new question.

Comment: "Unfortunately, at this point, the question has too much baggage to reopen." This. Whatever we do with this question now, it's going to be a mess - best just to leave it closed.